# Finding the maximal graphs to find the Ramsey number $R(P_4,C_7)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification, ramsey-theory

For my introduction to combinatorics class, we are being asked to compute the Ramsey number for $R(P_4,C_7)$ where $R(P_4,C_7)=k$ is the minimum number of vertices needed such that the 2-coloring of $K_k$ contains either a monochromatic $P_4$ or a monochromatic $C_7$.

To do this, I used a lemma/note from class stating that the connected components of a (maximal) $P_4$ graph are:

[image],

[image],

[image],

and the star on $n$ vertices (here is photo example of it on 7 vertices:

[image]).

Using this info, I found (I think) all the maximal graphs on 7 vertices that do not contain a $P_4$. So if we were coloring $K_7$ red and blue, let the edges shown in the graphs below be the red coloring and the edges in the complement of the graphs be the blue coloring. I just wanted to ensure that these were the only ones as then obviously in their complements there will be a blue $P_4$ which should prove that $R(P_4,C_7)=7$. Here are those five graphs in question:

First:

[image: 1]

Second:

[image: 2]

Third:

[image: 3]

Fourth:

[image: 4]

Fifth:

[image: 5]

All of which obviously have $P_4$ in it's complement.

My concern stems from [this paper](https://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Espr/PUBL/paper61.pdf) which on page 10 Theorem 9, it states:

$$R(P_n,C_m)=
 \begin{cases} 
      2n − 1 & \text{for $3 \leq m \leq n$, $m$ odd} \\
      n − 1 + \frac m 2 & \text{for $4 \leq m \leq n$, $m$ even} \\
      \max\{ m − 1 + \lfloor \frac n 2\rfloor, 2n − 1 \} & \text{for $2 \leq n \leq m$, $m$ odd} \\
m − 1 + \lfloor \frac n 2\rfloor & \text{for $2 \leq n \leq m$, $m$ even}
  \end{cases}
$$

But that would mean $R(P_4,C_7)=\max\{ 7 − 1 + \lfloor \frac 4 2\rfloor, 2\cdot 4 − 1 \}=\max\{ 8, 7 \}=8\neq 7$. I most certainly did something wrong but it's been an hour now and I cannot find the counterexample. At least I believe there is a counterexample I am not seeing.

Also, apologizes if the formatting around the photos is strange/makes the post enlongated. I tried doing the thing where you add s to the end of the MathSE link to the photo but that created weirder inconsistencies and photo quality issues (at least in the preview).

Thanks in advanced for the help and cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't you be searching for a $C_7$ in the complements of these graphs, not for a $P_4$? You are looking for $R(P_4, C_7)$, not for $R(P_4, P_4)$.

Comment: While, based on your proof, a $7$-vertex graph has a monochromatic $P_4$, you cannot "choose" which color it is. The property of the Ramsey number is that **every** coloring has to have a red $P_4$ or a blue $C_7$ -- if you "chose" your coloring, you would be flipping the colors of the graph, which would give you another coloring! As an example, the star on $7$ vertices has no red $P_4$ and blue $C_7$, so $R(P_4, C_7) > 7$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ah yes you are correct. I was mistaking the or in the definition as choosing what to look for.

Comment: @koifish that was exactly my mistake. Thank you. I also see why this would have to be 8 and not 7. I will add to my post with the correct images, etc when I get home. I believe this mistake was spurred on from just having done $R(C_4,C_4)$.

Comment: Well, to solve the question, you know $7$-vertex graphs don't work, so you just need to enumerate $8$-vertex graphs without a $P_4$ as you have done above and show that every one of them has a $C_7$ complement.